# Rails 4 passing information through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use this [video_info gem](https://github.com/thibaudgg/video_info) to implement it into my app, but want to know how to implement it so when user saves a video into the database, I'll be able to save some of the information as well.

I have this form:

```
= simple_form_for @challenge, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f|
  = f.input :video_url
  = f.button :submit, "Upload video"
```

Then in my controller:

```
def create
  @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @challenge.save
      format.html { redirect_to @challenge, notice: 'Challenge was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @challenge }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @challenge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @challenge.update(challenge_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @challenge, notice: 'Challenge was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @challenge }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @challenge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  def set_challenge
    @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])
  end

  def challenge_params
    params.require(:challenge).permit(:video_url :video_img).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

When user uploads a video url, somehow, the `:video_img` gets saved through this:

```
video = VideoInfo.new('http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x7lni3')
video.thumbnail_large
```

I'm not sure where to put the `VideoInfo.new`. In addition, is there an easy way to ensure that the image gets updated if user updates the video url?

Edit:

Adding `VideoInfo.new(params[:video_url])` into create action, getting error

[image]

With another change, per comment

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating your `video_img` attribute in `Challenge` model?

Comment: @Abhinay can you explain a little more in details? or example?

Comment: You must be having `video_img` attribute in your `Challenge` model, So, updating the attribute for ex: `@challenge = Challenge.new(...params goes here..)` then `video = VideoInfo.new('url prams goes here')` finally `@challenge.video_img = video.thumbnail_large` and ofcourse you need to save it.

Comment: @Abhinay I guess my question was where do I put `video = VideoInfo.new('http....')`? Because the url is going to be dynamic and should be taken from the form, and then on submit, the video thumbnail is saved into the record.

Comment: So, why cant you use `VideoInfo.new(params[:challenge_video_url])` before saving the record.

Comment: @Abhinay I added it into create action, but getting an error. I edited my post to see a screen shot. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Can you try changing it to `VideoInfo.new("#{params[:video_url]}")`

Comment: @Abhinay getting another error this time: `Url is not usable by any Providers:` and its just blank without providing what the Providers are? Uploaded a screenshot in the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101556/discussion-between-abhinay-and-hellomello).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to add `VideoInfo` right before you are about to save the record.

```
def create
  @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
  video = VideoInfo.new("#{params[:challenge][:video_url]}") # <-- Here
  @challenge.video_img = video.thumbnail_large
  respond_to do |format|
    if @challenge.save
      format.html { redirect_to @challenge, notice: 'Challenge was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @challenge }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @challenge.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Also, When `updating` check for the value change for `video_url` if it is changed then you might want to use these two line again:

```
video = VideoInfo.new("#{params[:challenge][:video_url]}")
@challenge.video_img = video.thumbnail_large
```

and finally update the record.